# NodeJS: What's the best way to share session between server-rendered views and React app

Tags: node.js, session, reactjs, websocket, koa

I have a NodeJS (Koa) server app that renders pages from the server i.e. nunjucks/jade/etc. The login page is also server rendered. Upon login, cookies are created.

Now I'm building a react app that will be embedded in a secure page (after user logs in). What's the best way to have that react app make secure Http/Websocket requests to the server using the user's currently logged in session?

Currently, I am injecting the sessionId into the server-rendered page's script tag where the React app gets loaded. So...

Server:

```
var session = require('koa-generic-session');
app.use(session({
    store: redisStore(...)
}));
app.use(function*(next) {
    this.state.sessionIdFromServer = this.sessionId;
    return yield next
});
```

Client:

```
<script>
var sessionId = {{sessionIdFromServer}};
</script>
...
<div id='app'> react app loads here </div>
```

Then I use that **sessionId** variable in my client-side HTTP/WebSocket requests (particularly websocket).

For each request made by client (passing sessionId in case of sockets), the server basically checks Redis session store to see if that session is still valid (i.e. not expired or logged out), before fulfilling the request.

Is this a feasible/secure-enough approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, what I should do is just use cookies for your session. That way any front end AJAX calls (including WebSocket) will use the cookie in the request headers.

With the `HTTP Only` setting set on the cookie, no front end JavaScript can modify (or access) the session cookie, but it is still used by the browser on any outgoing request.

In my opinion this is the safest way for using the session id, without the front end needing to know about the existence of the cookie in the first place.

If the session in koa doesn't exist any more, you automatically know the user is logged out as well.

I've made a little example for this (there is a Github link below):

**First the `index.js`:**

```
'use strict';

const session = require('koa-session');
const koa = require('koa');
const websockify = require('koa-websocket');
const route = require('koa-route');

const app = websockify(koa());

app.keys = ['some secret hurr'];
const sessionStore = session(app);

app.use(sessionStore);
app.ws.use(sessionStore);

app.use(route.all('/', function* (next) {
  // ignore favicon
  if (this.path === '/favicon.ico') return;

  let n = this.session.views || 0;
  this.session.views = ++n;
  yield next;
}));

app.ws.use(route.all('/', function* (next) {
  this.websocket.on('message', (message) => {
    let n = this.session.views || 0;
    this.session.views = ++n;

    if (message === 'ping') {
      // Return the amount of sessions (n) when the client sends ping
      this.websocket.send('pong ' + n);
    }
  });

  yield next;
}));

app.use(require('koa-static')('./public'));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on port 3000');
```

**And then the `index.html`:**

```
<html>
  <script>
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/");

    ws.onopen = function() {
      // Sends a message
      ws.send("ping");  
    };

    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
      // Receives a message.
      alert(e.data);
    };

    ws.onclose = function() {
      alert("closed");
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

I've put all of this in to a working example [on GitHub](https://github.com/bcallaars/nodejs-whats-the-best-way-to-share-session-between-server-rendered-views-and-r).